# Export C# Code listings as HTML code with colour syntax

Tags: c#, wordpress

I have a free Wordpress blog, which unfortunately I cannot use plug-ins to colour code my C#.

Is there a free plugin for Visual Studio 2010/Express that exports code to HTML code with colour syntax?  Or a website that you can paste code into and it colour codes it to HTML?

Comment: I think if you put [sourcecode language="CSharp"] it will work in WordPress.com free hosting. You don't require any plugins. - Yes, its not answering your question, but hope it will help.

Comment: I found this that works with VS Pro -> http://devonenote.com/2010/04/copysourceashtml-for-visual-studio-2010/#more-313. VS Express does not appear to have addins.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

<strike>[SyntaxHighlighter Evolved](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/syntaxhighlighter/)</strike>

[SyntaxHighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/SyntaxHighlighter/manual/installation.html) —  JavaScript syntax highlighter

Comment: Didn't the OP say he couldn't use Wordpress plugins?

Comment: @chibacity: Very good point (doh).  In which case he could use the SyntaxHighlighter the original JavaScript version.

Comment: Thanks but I dont think I can add base files to a page: shCore.js and shCore.css